# Android Sqlite Statement Question

Tags: sql, android, sqlite

Lets say I have a database with tables called box, item, and box_contents and I want to get any item that is contained in the box_content table (all items, but discard the ones that arent in the box_contents table). What would be the correct sqllite syntax for this?

Comment: NB:  This is a pretty basic SQL / query question.  I suggest learning more about SQL / database querying before continuing your project, unless you had an extremely short term need.  Or you're going to be smashing your head against your desk or Android phone, causing long-term damage to your head or phone.  Neither of which is good. :)

Comment: I am fairly familiar with joins but I know Android doesn't support right and full joins. So I wanted to make sure that there isn't a special way to do it in Android.

Comment: Based on your question in English, Alex Martelli or I should be correct.  Unless you post actual code, I don't think you'll be to get too much help.

Comment: Yea it looks like you guys are so many thanks, but now I am having a problem with "_id field does not exist" So it looks like query is working but I assume they want the _id field of both tables returned, since I am returning one and still getting the error. After I figure this out I will let you guys know.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on your schema, that is, how does your "box_content" table denote that it "contains" a certain item.  For example, if it does so by having a column "ItemId" that's a foreign reference to the "item" table's primary key "Id", then

```
SELECT item.*
FROM item
JOIN box_content ON (box_content.ItemId = item.Id)
```

would work fine (assuming you do mean exactly what you say, i.e. that you want items contained *anywhere* in the "box_content" table, and that your mention of yet another table "box" is actually completely irrelevant).

But, if your schema is completely different (or what you actually want to do is quite different from what you said), then of course so will the needed SQL.  What about editing your Q to show the `CREATE TABLE` statements and (if needed) any comments abut them...?

Answer (score 0):

You will want to do what's called a [join](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29) between the two tables.

You'd have something like:

```
SELECT (item_columns)
FROM item i JOIN box_contents bc ON i.item_id = bc.item_id
```